# Expo v4 / React : Passing datas between tab screen

Tags: react-native, expo

Expo v4..

Hello friends,

I am using expo tab navigation:
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/hello-react-navigation

How can I pass datas bewteen expo tabs ?

**OrderScreen.tsx:**

```
import { createMaterialTopTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/material-top-tabs';

const Tab = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();

export default function OrderScreen({navigation, route}) {

let data = route.params

    return (
      <Tab.Navigator>
      <Tab.Screen name="Details" component={DetailsScreen} />  
      <Tab.Screen name="Photos" component={PhotosScreen} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
    );
  }
```

**PhotosScreen.tsx:**

```
export default function PhotosScreen() {

// HOW TO GET route.params here ??
```

**DetailScreen.tsx:**

```
export default function DetailsScreen() {

// HOW TO GET route.params here ??
```

I manage to have data in only one tab using :

```
navigation.navigate('Order', {screen: 'Details' ,params: {datas:someDatas}});
```

But I want to have the datas in both tabs.

I have been searching everywhere but impossible to find.
I would be very surprise there is no solution for that.

T H A N K S  !!!! :-)

Answer (score 0):

finding no answer on the net, I've been using the context api.
for a guy new to react it took a while to get the idea of context but it seems to be quite powerful once settled.